# Issue with coocur() handling abundance vs logical data

Tags: r

Can `coocur()` in R, use `TRUE`/`FALSE` data or does it have to be a binary dataframe or matrix? I am asking because I realized that after analysis I found that it will work with a `TRUE`/`FALSE` matrix, but yields different answers:

```
With TRUE/FALSE data: 
    Call:
    cooccur(mat = species_site, type = "spp_site", thresh = T, spp_names = TRUE, 
        prob = "comb")
    
    Of 378 species pair combinations, 309 pairs (81.75 %) were removed from the analysis because expected co-occurrence was < 1 and 69 pairs were analyzed
    
    Cooccurrence Summary:
           Species          Sites       Positive       Negative         Random 
              28.0           14.0            8.0            0.0           57.0 
    Unclassifiable Non-random (%) 
               4.0           11.6 
    attr(,"class")
    
        With abundance data: 
Call:
    cooccur(mat = species_site, type = "spp_site", thresh = T, spp_names = TRUE, 
        prob = "comb")
    
    Of 378 species pair combinations, 159 pairs (42.06 %) were removed from the analysis because expected co-occurrence was < 1 and 219 pairs were analyzed
    
    Cooccurrence Summary:
           Species          Sites       Positive       Negative         Random 
              28.0           14.0          188.0          199.0           17.0 
    Unclassifiable Non-random (%) 
            -185.0           90.9 
    attr(,"class")
    
        # A tibble: 14 × 28
       Arachnida Araneae Carabidae Cerambycidae Cryptarcha.ampla Diptera Diptera.larvae
           <int>   <int>     <int>        <int>            <int>   <int>          <int>
     1         0       2         0            0                0       0              0
     2         0       1         0            0                0       1              0
     3         0       1         0            0                0       0              0
     4         0       0         0            0                0       0              0
     5         0       0         0            0                0       0              0
     6         0       1         0            0                0       1              1
     7         3       2         1            0                0       5              2
     8         0       3         3            1                0      11              1
     9         0       4         0            0                0       2              0
    10         0       0         1            0                0       0              1
    11         0       1         0            0                0       0              0
    12         0       0         0            0                1       0              0
    13         0       1         0            0                0       0              0
    14         0       2         0            0                0       0              0
```

Comment: Where is `coocur()` defined? How are you calling it?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cooccur/cooccur.pdf
`Page 4`

Comment: I cannot reproduce different results when the data is logical. R codes `FALSE/TRUE` as integers `0/1` and the results of running the example in `help("cooccur")` with numeric or logical data are exactly the same. VTC as not reproducible.